# representation of a measurable set in a sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a non-empty set and assume $\Gamma$ be  a family of subsets of $\Omega$.  Let us denote $\sigma(\Gamma)$, by the sigma algebra generated by $\Gamma$.

Please look at the following paragraph:

For a given  $A$   in $\sigma(\Gamma)$, one may find a sequence $A_1,A_2,\cdots$ in $\Gamma$ such that $A$ is also contained in the sigma algebra generated by the sequence $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$.

What do you say if it is supposed to give a proof for it?

Comment: Just check that $\bigcup \{\sigma(\Delta) : \Delta \subseteq \Gamma, \Delta \text{ countable} \}$ is a sigma algebra.